# How to sum a single table column using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a generated table on my JSP that contains data for transactions: each individual transaction is a row, and there's a column for category, amount, type, and description.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="res">
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="element" items="${sessionScope.pick}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${element.category}" /></td>
                <td class="countable">
                    <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencyCode="USD" 
                    value="${element.amount}"></fmt:formatNumber>
                </td>
                <td><c:out value="${element.entry_Type}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${element.description}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

So it comes out as

Category____Amount____Type____Description

My table is populated using Struts: I select a department on another JSP, then press "display" to forward to the page that generates the table.  Because of this, the table won't necessarily have a set number of rows.  What I'm trying to do is add up the Amount column from each transaction so I can display the total.  I tried to do this using Javascript but it hasn't worked for me:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">

    var cls = document.getElementById("res").getElementsByTagName("td");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
        if(tds[i].className == "countable"){
            sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML.append("<tr><td> Total Balance </td><td>" + sum + "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
</script>
```

Can anyone see where I've messed up, or what a better option might be?  Also, is there a way to sum the columns and display the total without adding another row to the table?  That would be ideal if possible.

Comment: No point to do it using javascript, but in jsp you can use a simple counter.

Comment: Did you mean something like this `<c:forEach var="total" items="${res}">
     <td>${total.value}</td>
  </c:forEach>`

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `tds` should be named `cls`. Here is a working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/34wf5gzs/

```
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
    if(cls[i].className == "countable"){
        sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

[Roman C is right though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232127/how-to-sum-a-single-table-column-using-javascript/35232483#comment58179491_35232127). You're better off summing this up using a JS framework or using a counter in JSP. Custom scripts require some effort to maintain.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that variable name... Thanks for the example, however if I try to add it to the table it just comes up blank.  Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: `innerHTML` is of type text and does not have an append method. You need to replace the text instead. I've an updated example for you - https://jsfiddle.net/34wf5gzs/1/

Comment: When I try to run your example myself the sum comes up as zero.  I haven't been able to figure out why that's happening.

Answer (score 2):

I have no knowledge about JSP but i assume that Roman C is right.

But if you wan't to solve this with javascript here is a working example:

```
var sum = 0;
var table = document.getElementById("res");
var ths = table.getElementsByTagName('th');
var tds = table.getElementsByClassName('countable');
for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerText) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerText);
}

var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.setAttribute('colspan', ths.length);

var totalBalance  = document.createTextNode('Total Balance ' + sum);
cell.appendChild(totalBalance);
```

Link to a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4cetuvno/1/

Comment: I like this idea but it doesn't work when I run it myself.  I get total balance 0.

Comment: If you look at the markup in my jsfiddle does it match with your markup? The ids, classes and so on. If it does i don't see why it would not work. 

When do you run that js code? Is the table rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I have table ABC with is having a column xyz. Based on that we need to update input as "sum" as a total of xyz.

```
function updateTotal(){
    var table = document.getElementById("ABC");
    var x = table.rows.length;
    var sumVal = 0;
    for (let i = 3; i < x-4; i++) {
        var value = table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        if(value != null && ""!= value && !isNaN(value)){
            var valueToAdd = parseInt(value);
            sumVal = sumVal+valueToAdd;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML="<td style='font-size: large;' id='sum'>"+sumVal+"</td>";
}
```